# How to add space in between TLV's(Tag Length Value) from String?

Tags: java

```
String tlv="80037665658104727265668203726564";
```

I want to print the above string TLV's separated with space like below

```
8003766565 810472726566 8203726564
```

eg. 80 -- Tag
    03 -- Lengh
    766565 -- value (every 2 digits like one byte total 3 bytes length)

Please help me above issue.

Comment: Can you please explain your condition more accurately

Comment: tlv is the hex decimal string with form of one or more TLV's are have with in string. I want to iterate the every TLV and perform operations on that. But i don't know how to iterate the different lengths of TLV's from string.

Comment: Every TLV has Tag, Length and Value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static String tlv(String str1)
{
    String slim="";
    String str=str1+"00";
    int tlvlen=0;
    while(str.substring(tlvlen+0,tlvlen+2).matches("AA|A4|A9|1E|C0|C1|C2|C3|C4|C5|C6|C7|C8|C9|CA|CB|CC|A8|A0|4F|50|51|52|53|54|61|73|80|81|82|83|84|85|86|87|88|89|95"))
    {
    int len=Convertion.hex2decimal(str.substring(tlvlen+2,tlvlen+4))*2+4;
    String tlv=str.substring(tlvlen,len+tlvlen);
    slim+=tlv+" ";

    tlvlen=tlv.length()+tlvlen;
    }
    return slim;
}
```

hear the convertion class has the hex2decimal method. This method will convert length hex to decimal.

```
public class Convertion {

public static int hex2decimal(String s) {
    String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    s = s.toUpperCase();
    int val = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        int d = digits.indexOf(c);
        val = 16 * val + d;
    }
    return val;
}}
```